# Can't checkout master branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I've been working in a branch with some code to improve an application. Now that it's finished, I want to merge this branch with master branch, but I can't. I first tried to checkout to master branch like this:

```
$ git checkout master
```

but I get this error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
vendor/bin/doctrine
vendor/bin/doctrine.php
...
```

but the vendor directory is included in `.gitignore` file.
If I execute:

```
$ git status
```

I get this message:

```
# On branch mejoras_contralador
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

After this, I would do:

```
$ git merge branch
```

How to avoid this error?

Comment: The way I read it, your files are in `.gitignore` on the current branch, but not on `master`, so checking it out would lose working directory contents, which git tends to try to avoid.  Hence the error message.

Comment: That's it. But I've already removed the repo and cloned again.

Comment: My bad, I read this from the review queue and didn't notice the relevant answer was already there.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @mu無 - Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800199/how-to-ignore-directories-and-files-only-inside-a-directory

Comment: @ManoloSalsas I went through that, but it seems to be a completely different question. Here, the problem seemed to be with `vendors` directory, there it is about `.gitignore` rules for `web/` directory.

Comment: @mu無 - So much time since this question. I finally removed the repository and cloned it again.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas Yeah, I realized that. Anyway, my intention was to check if my answer helped you correct the problem in this question.

Comment: @mu無 - Not sure. Anyway +1 to your detailed answer.

Answer (score 6):

So the problem here is, that on your current branch (lets call it `current`), the `vendor` directory is in `.gitignore` and is not a part of the repo.

However, it is committed in your `master` branch and thus, your master branch is throwing the error `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout`

The solution is simple.

1) In your branch `current`, rename your vendor directory to some other directory (say `vendor.temp`, you can use `mv vendor vendor.temp`)

2) Now do a `git checkout master`. This won't throw any conflicts this time, since there is no common vendor directory already existing on the branch you are trying to checkout from.

3) Now run a `git rm -r --cached vendor` on your `master` branch. This will remove the vendor directory from being tracked in your `master` branch.

4) Update the `.gitignore` file in your `master` branch to start ignoring `vendor` directory. Commit corresponding changes

5) Decide which vendor directory you need, the `vendor` directory in branch `master`, or `vendor` directory that was there in branch `current`, and rename/remove files accordingly.

Comment: Uf!! I've got into a mess. When I tried to do `git checkout master` it told me to commit the changes, and after all, I still got an error. Finally, I've decided to sart again cloning my remote repo, but I see that `vendor`, `app/cache` and `app/logs` are not created. I guess it is because `gitignore`, but `vendor/*` f.e., means that files and directories **inside** `vendor` directory are not commited. I'm really confused.

Comment: Can you tell me them exact steps you ran?

Comment: I've asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800199/how-to-ignore-directories-and-files-only-inside-a-directory

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

git rm --cached vendor/bin/doctrine.php

and for all files you've ignored but get this status.

Comment: Things like vendor/bin/* should work. And a small shell script would also do the trick.

Comment: `git rm --cached vendor/*` -> `fatal: pathspec 'vendor/autoload.php' did not match any files`

Comment: It would seem that not all files are tracked in this directory. Are there so many to pick them individually?

Comment: Maybe somewhat more pragmatic: can you delete or move them?

Comment: Add `--ignore-unmatch` to tell `git rm --cached` that files in the directory, but not in the repo, can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

add the files`(git add)` and start tracking them and stash them `(git stash)` and then you can do  `git checkout master`

Comment: Th working directory is clean, so I guess doing `git stash` or `git add` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, the files should be ignored but have already been committed, and you need to remove them with `git rm --cached`.

However, according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790711/cant-checkout-master-branch#comment27708532_18790782), it seems that the files are untracked in current branch but exist in the master branch? I think you need to delete the files in your in the current branch (move it somewhere else), check out the master branch, `git rm --cached` the files, and merge the two branches.