# How to ignore directories and files only inside a directory

Tags: git

I have this `.gitignore` file:

```
app/cache/*
app/logs/*
app/bootstrap*
vendor/*
web/bundles/
app/config/parameters.yml
web/public/img/users/*
```

but I want the directory `web/public/img/users` not to be ignored (only files inside).
I mean, when a `git clone repo` is done, the directory must be made, but not the files inside. How can I do it?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories, only files. PoByBolek has a very good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `.gitignore` file into `web/public/img/users/` that ignores everything and add this `.gitignore` to your repository.

Comment: No! Seems that if the only file in the directory is the `.gitignore` file, the directory is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add empty directories to a git repository. A workaround is to create a *.gitignore* file in every folder that should be added without any files or subdirectories inside.

The *.gitignore* must look like this:

```
# ignore everything but .gitignore
*
!/.gitignore
```

It is a workaround because you must add one *.gitignore* to every folder and therefore the folder is not completely empty. And you might loose the overview of ignored files compared to having only one *.gitignore* file in the root.